# Gradle buildtypes override each other

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I want to set different values for a property depending on which buildType was chosen. But I realized by checking the gradle console that in configuration phase all 3 buildTypes are executed and the value of the last build remains in the property. I think that's not how it should work. 
Did I do something wrong?

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        ...
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }

    productFlavors {
        normal {
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "@string/app_name"]
            signingConfig signingConfigs.configNormalRelease
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            println("app release build")
            rootProject.ext.test = false
        }
        debug {
            println("app debug build")
            rootProject.ext.test = false
        }
        staging {
            println("app staging build")
            rootProject.ext.test = true
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/aidl']
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds true
        abortOnError false
    }
    flavorDimensions 'tier'
    productFlavors {
        normal {
            dimension "tier"
        }
    }
}
```

Output is

```
app release build
app debug build
app staging build
```

value of 'test' property is always true, whether I call assembleRelease, assembleDebug, assembleStaging

Why I see everywhere that people put api keys, urls, and other custom stuff into buildTypes when they get overridden by the last one? I understand that gradle might call all buildtypes during configuration phase, but where to put above mentions values then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get your `test` value from source code in your project, you can set variable:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'test', 'false'
    }
    debug {
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'test', 'false'
    }
    staging {
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'test', 'true'
    }
}
```

And then you can get this field from your code using `BuildConfig` class (`test` field will be generated into`BuildConfig`). Get it through `BuildConfig.test`.

And if you really want to change gradle variable for any buildTypes, you can try to do this:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
  boolean isStaging = gradle.startParameter.taskNames.find {it.contains("staging") || it.contains("Staging")} != null
  if (isStaging) {
    rootProject.ext.test = true
  } else {
    rootProject.ext.test = false
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks more like a a workaround rather then a wanted implementation, but I understood it now. Thank you very much !